# Numerical methods for solving trajectories in Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, general-relativity

I'm working on some trajectories in general relativity and I've worked myself to these 2 equations
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{dr}{d\lambda}\right)^2=\frac{l^2}{b^2}+\frac{l^2}{r^2}\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}\right)^2=\frac{l^2}{r^4}
\end{equation}
where $r$ and $\phi$ are polar coordinates, $M,b$ and $l$ are known constants and $\lambda$ is an affine parameter.

My plan is to solve these numerically to get trajectory in polar coordinates. I'm just not really sure how to go about this, since I've never done it before. I thought about dividing one into another which gives me
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{dr}{d\phi}\right)^2=r^4\left(\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)\right)
\end{equation}
and then solve this equation using for example the RK4 method (If there is any better method to do this please let me know).

Is this the right way to go about this?

Comment: As often in gravitational equations, you get some degree of simplification by replacing $r=1/u$. Then only the situation around $r=0$ needs careful treatment.

Comment: The 3/8 method has half the error of RK4. But what are the actual demands on the numerical integration? Could you also use a solver from some numerical library?

Comment: There aren't really any demands, I just need to plot the trajectory, mostly just qualitatively, to see it's shape.

Comment: Then you can use any DoPri (4)5 or LSODA solver, these exist in most solver libraries. Explicitly set the error tolerances. But $u'(ϕ)^2=\frac1{b^2}+u^2(1-2Mu)$ should also be easy to analyze from the formula.